What problems may I experience if I'd place C++ project dependencies directly into the project? (Or why use find_package() at all?)
Why use find_package() at all in CMake? Isn't it better to just place all deps in a special folder like "libs" and then add it via add_subdirectory()? It's easier especially on Windows, I don't have to set up all those dep. managment tools like vcpkg. That way I could place libraries with a specific version I may need. And if I clone that CMake project in another PC, I could easily compile it with no extra setup. I think it's super simple and convenient.
But could this approach lead me to some problems I don't see currently?

One negative depending on your situation is it can take a lot of time to rebuild the dependent libraries and they may very negatively impact performance of your IDE if they are part of your project. Several of my dependent libraries are several hundred thousand lines of code to several million and have dozens of libraries as part of the project (not counting the unit tests and demo code).
